# React - ternary operator and sonar

Tags: reactjs, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarlint

How can i solve this problem with ternary operators, and why sonar don't accept it?

[image]

Comment: Please include code as text not images. [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: to be honest, stackoverflow should develop a service to read all the text from the pictures that people posted :) Just a thought, even mac supports it now.

Comment: @windmaomao The issue with using OCR on code is that it introduces one more place that a typo might be added. And besides, copy-pasting text is arguably easier than taking a screenshot, and certainly more reliable.

Answer (score 1):

this is not a simple operator. It could be intented, but you have to be aware of what happened here.

```
  const a = flag ? (b = 2) : null
```

You get the results like the following

```
  if (flag) { b = 2 }
  const a = flag ? b : null
```

So essentially i don't think it complains about the conditional statement, but more towards the potential assignment.

Maybe we can change the code to this and see if it works.

```
  if (flag) { statement }
  const a = conditional assignment
```

Comment: I got the same problem even if the code is for example : 

isEditing ? setSomething : setSomethingElse() ;

Comment: `setSomethingElse()` is the same idea, isn't it? :) so I guess it want you to do two things separately, statement and assignment. I know it's a bit odd. But the statement isn't pure, that's something maybe it complains.

Comment: If I do for any ternary a thing like this :
  if(isEditing) {
      doSomething();
  else {
     doSomethingElse();
}

with this method i can solve it but I was wondering if it is possible to it with ternary operator

Comment: Here's the thing, depending on what you do in the statement. `const a = true ? a.find() : null`, this is pure. However if you do `const a = true ? setState(3) : null`. This is bad. Why? you are changing external state. So better write it with a `if` statement. I guess, the bottom line is that, we don't want to hide things too complicated in a ternary operator.

Comment: Ok , thank you! I will try

Comment: Not a problem Chris, btw, that was just my guts feeling. To be honest, i think your argument is also valid.